# Wordpress Plugin to Show a Website in Different Language?

Tags: plugins

Well I am looking for a plugin which will let visitors to browse a site in different languages. Lets say an user just landed on my site and a popup will be appear asking whether the visitor want to browse the site into English or Bengali? If the user select on Bengali then the site will be shown to him in Bengali language otherwise it would run into its default language.

Is this possible? If possible then please guide me to implement it in my site.

Comment: See this solution http://multilingualpress.pro/ the source is here, public https://github.com/inpsyde/multilingual-press

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This plug-in works well, though you typically have to create separate subdomains for each language.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/multisite-language-switcher/